# Removing messages from output (Skycoord)

Tags: python, astropy

I am working with astropy's skycoord feature, and had the following problem:

```
x= [201.3, 214.5, 201.6]
y= [49.6, 51.89, 43.2]

coord = SkyCoord(x1, y1, frame="icrs", unit="deg")
```

Now when I print `coord` I get the following output:

```
[<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    (201.3,49.6) >, <SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    (214.5,51.89)>, <SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    (201.6,43.2)>]
```

My problem is that I don't want the `[<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg` message. I just want pairs of those numbers in a list. I tried if statements but didn't have any luck. I am stuck on how to approach this problem. Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: `print` only returns a string representation of the object and is not the right way to access such values. There ought to be some dedicated method or attribute to get those numbers, something like `coord.x`, but I don't know what exactly it is in your case as I'm not familiar with the data structure. You need to check the docs of the library in order to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick note: I don't think the code you posted is what you actually ran.  From your output it looks like you made an array of multiple `SkyCoord` objects, with one for each pair of ra/dec coordinates; something like:

```py
x = [201.3, 214.5, 201.6]
y = [49.6, 51.89, 43.2]

coords = []

for x1, y1 in zip(x, y):
    coord = SkyCoord(x1, y1, frame="icrs", unit="deg")
    coords.append(coord)
```

It's not necessary to do this--you can pass `SkyCoord` a list/array of values for each coordinate:

```
>>> ra = [201.3, 214.5, 201.6]
>>> dec = [49.6, 51.89, 43.2]
>>> coord = SkyCoord(ra, dec, frame="icrs", unit="deg")
>>> coord
<SkyCoord (ICRS): (ra, dec) in deg
    [(201.3, 49.6 ), (214.5, 51.89), (201.6, 43.2 )]>
```

`SkyCoord` is a Python object which serves as a container for many pieces of information: Including the coordinate values themselves, what units the coordinates are in, the frame, the coordinate system, etc.

It's typical for any complex Python object that its default string format is something that tells you what type of object it is, and what is the most important data contained by it.  The "message" here is just the value of the object itself.

If you want to display some particular piece of information (e.g. in a script you're writing) it can't make assumptions about what you want to show, because many people will have many different use cases for it.

It wasn't entirely clear from your question as the the exact purpose you want to display the coordinates.  That is, what exactly is the form of your desired output?  Depending on exactly what you want there might be different ways to do it.

For example, there is a [`SkyCoord.to_string()`] method that has many options for returning plain string representations for a coordinate, for printing, etc.

Using the example `coord` object I made above:

```py
>>> coord.to_string()
['201.3 49.6', '214.5 51.89', '201.6 43.2']
```

you can see it returns a list of strings, one for each coordinate pair.  You could print these each individually like:

```py
>>> for c in coord.to_string():
...     print(c)
...
 
201.3 49.6
214.5 51.89
201.6 43.2
```

It's unfortnate that there aren't more examples in the documentation, but you can see that `to_string()` has many different options for formatting.

Comment: `SkyCoord.to_string()` was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you